# Changes to T-SQL between SQL Server 2008 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to find a list or explanation of any changes in T-SQL for MS SQL Server bewteen the 2008 release and the 2012 release.  I know this may be a broad question, but does anyone know if for basic SQL tasks (ALTER TABLE, SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, etc,) if there has been any changes to the T-SQL language syntax between 2008 and 2012?

I need to get some books and would rather get the newer (2012) version (so I don't have to rebuy the books again later) even though I'm still technically working with a SQL 2008 R2 server right row (but will be upgrading in the next year or so to 2012).

Comment: I don't think these DML syntax are changed. These should be the same. Generally new version of DB mostly focus on DB engine performance, memory management, new functions, etc. These DML you mentioned are standard SQL language. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I just found a document on MS's website discussing a brief overview of the changes.  Most changes are additions to T-SQL.  Doesn't appear that anything existing as far as T-SQL is concerned, has been removed or changed in terms of syntax or function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Books online is the best resource for these kind of informations.

[Whats new in SQL 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500435.aspx)

This link talks about the Programmability Enhancements

[Programmability Enhancements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09f0096e-ab95-4be0-8c01-f98753255747)